# SVM without offset

Tags: classification, svm, offset

I would like to know if the linear-SVM-without-offset solver:
$$\min \frac{1}{2}\|w\|^2+C\sum_{i=1}^m \xi_i, \quad \mbox{s.t.}\quad y_iw^\top x_i \geq 1-\xi_i, \quad \xi_i\geq 0 \quad \forall i=1,\ldots,m.$$
can be applied to classify linearly separable data, where the hyperplane does not pass through the origin.

Maybe a change of coordinate system would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear SVM can't do anything a linear model cannot do, so without a bias term, the hyperplane must pass through the origin.  This can be addressed by adding an extra input feature with a constant value (which is how a bias term is often implemented in linear regression).

Comment: Hi @Dikran. Thanks for the answer.
Could you please be more specific about "adding an extra input feature..."? 

My thinking:

Suppose that we have already an "SVMs-without-bias" solver $F(X,y,C)$ (that returns $w$ and $\xi$).

Now for an instance $(X,y,C)$, where the data $(X,y)$ are linearly separable by a hyperplane that does not pass through the origin, if one applies a suitable rotation to the data to obtain $X',y'$ (i.e. we go to another space, the same idea as "feature space" in kernels), then the above solver can be used to classify the new (rotated) features: $F(X',y',C)$.

Comment: I understand now. We can either use a rotation or a translation. What you have suggested is a translation, which is much simpler than a rotation.

In this case, we have to solve another problem than "SVM-without-offset", haven't we? (I mean we cannot use the "SVMs-without-bias" solver).

Comment: If you just add an extra column of ones to $X$, then that will give an implicit bias parameter, even though you can still use the "SVMs-without-bias" solver.  The extra element of $w$ will be the bias term.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking forward. I read it once somewhere but then couldn't find it again. Thank you so much, @Dikran!
(P/s: It would be nice if you edit the answer and replace it by this comment).